# Javascript Newbie...How do you store an object property as a variable and its value as another?

Tags: javascript, variables, object, properties

I have the later mentioned object array and I would love to store the actual property "string" as a variable and the value in a seperate variable using javascript. Is that possible and if so how?

```
states = {
    "Alaska": 663267,
    "Texas": 268581,
    "California": 163696,
    "Montana": 147042,
    "New Mexico": 121589,
    "Arizona": 113998,
    "Nevada": 110561
};
```

Comment: Could you please specify what's the expected output given the above input? Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: you would then have just a bunch of vars instead of a collection in the form of an object, is that what you want?

Comment: Where is this "object array"?

Comment: [for ... in ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: I am going to create a table dynamically. With the property falling under the first column and the square miles falling in the second

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like the following:

```
// This would be the constructor 
// for an object with two values
// One for the city and one for the miles.
function CityMiles(city, miles){
    this.city = city;
    this.miles = miles;
}

// This is the array, which will hold the CityMiles objects.
var citiesMiles = [];

// Iterate through the keys of states
for(var key in states){
    if(states.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        // Push in the citiesMiles array a new CityMiles object
        // for the current state.
        citiesMiles.push(new CityMiles(key, states[key]));
    } 
}
```

Below is a snippet to see it in action.

```js
var states = {
    "Alaska": 663267,
    "Texas": 268581,
    "California": 163696,
    "Montana": 147042,
    "New Mexico": 121589,
    "Arizona": 113998,
    "Nevada": 110561
};


function CityMiles(city, miles){
   this.city = city;
   this.miles = miles;
}
    

var citiesMiles = [];
    
for(var key in states){
    if(states.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        citiesMiles.push(new CityMiles(key, states[key]));
    } 
}


function addRow(city, miles) {
    var table = document.getElementById("cityMilesTable");
  
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
 
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= city;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= miles;
}

for(var i=0; i<citiesMiles.length; i++){
    addRow(citiesMiles[i].city, citiesMiles[i].miles);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table" id="cityMilesTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>City</th>
           <th>Miles</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```